# Find the rate of change of $f(x,y)=xy^2$ with respect to t along the curve $r(t)=e^{2t}i+e^{\frac{t}{2}}j$

Tags: calculus

How do you do the following.

Find the rate of change of $f(x,y)=xy^2$ with respect to t along the curve $r(t)=e^{2t}i+e^{\frac{t}{2}}j$

expressed in terms of t.

This is what I did first I found the gradient of f(x,y)

$y^2i+x(2y)j$

Then I took the derivative of r(t)

$r'(t)=2e^{2t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{t/2}$

Then I plug in for my $x=e^{2t}$ $y=e^{t/2}$ in the gradient  and dot product derivative

$ e^{\frac{t}{2}}+2e^{2t}e^{\frac{t}{2}}\cdot2e^{2t}+e^{\frac{t}{2}}\frac{1}{2}$  there should be a square in the most left

simplify a bit

$e^{\frac{t}{4}}+2e^{\frac{5}{2}}\cdot(2e^{2t}+e^{\frac{t}{2}}\frac{1}{2})$

thane answer is supposed to be $3e^{3t}$ but I do not see how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$r(t)=e^{2t}\hat{\mathbf{i}}+e^{t/2}\hat{\mathbf{j}}=x\hat{\mathbf{i}}+y\hat{\mathbf{j}}\\
\implies x=e^{2t},y=e^{t/2}\\
\implies f(x,y)=xy^2=e^{2t}e^{t}=e^{3t}\\
\implies \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f(x,y)}{\mathrm{d}t}=3e^{3t}\text{, from elementary differentiation.}$$

Comment: I see that makes sense I think I made my error with the exponent.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Yes, you differentiated the curve first. That was the error.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x,y)=xy^2$ and $x=e^{2t},y=e^{t/2}$, then you can find $f(t)$ by doing substitution.
$$f(t)=(e^{2t})(e^{t/2})^2=(e^{2t})(e^{t})=e^{3t}$$.

Now we can find $$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{d(e^{3t})}{dt}=3e^{3t}$$